# Java control flow

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

I'm currently working on the notReplace problem on codingbat. I've identified the section of code that is wrong but have not idea why. When notReplace("This is right") is called I get the output: "Thtest test right".
Why does the following section of the code run?

```
    else if (!(Character.isLetter(i-1)) && i+2<len && !(Character.isLetter(i+2))){
newStr += "test";
i++;
}
```

When i==2, charAt(i-1)=='h' so the first condition is already not satisfied, since h is a letter but 'is' still gets replaced with 'test'. Any help appreciated. Full code below:

```
    public String notReplace(String str) {
    String newStr = "";
    String iN = "is not";
    int len = str.length();

     for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
      if (str.substring(i,Math.min(i+2,len)).equals("is")){

       if (i==0 && i+2<len && !(Character.isLetter(i+2))){
        newStr += iN;
        i++;
       } 
       else if (i+2==len && !(Character.isLetter(i-1))){
        newStr += iN;
        i++;
        }
       else if (!(Character.isLetter(i-1)) && i+2<len && !(Character.isLetter(i+2))){
        newStr += "test";
        i++;
        }
       else newStr += str.charAt(i);
      }

      else newStr += str.charAt(i);
     }
     return newStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Character.isLetter(i - 1)` 
when `i =2`
 `Character.isLetter(i-1)` --> `Character.isLetter(1)`

so it's false and because `1` is not a letter . your first condition `!Character.isLetter(i - 1)` is true.you have missed `charAt(i-1)` part

you should use

`!Character.isLetter(charAt(i-1))`

Comment: i'm not sure is that what you are asking

Comment: Ah damn can't believe I didn't spot that, thanks so much for your help. Exactly what I wanted to know.